# How to deal with NA's in a if / ifelse if dataframe has NA's in it

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I'm new to R and I learned for loops today. I'm having an issue with running this loop. The dataframe should be linked here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpbFG.jpg
The df is called scores, and it has the names of the home and away countries that played in the world cup. It also shows the name of the country that won. When it was a tie, though, there is an NA. I tried to run my code with just if (homename = winnername), then i would add TRUE to the vector, since I am looking at whether the home team won. And if not (else) then put FALSE. I tried it another way where I mentioned the NA specifically and it gives me the same error:

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

But my code is as follows,

```
scorevector <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(scores)) {
  if (scores$home_country[i] == scores$win_country[i]) {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, TRUE)
  } else if (scores$win_country[i] == NA) {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, FALSE)
  } else {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, FALSE)
    }
  }
```

This was the other version

```
scorevector <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(scores)) {
  if (scores$home_country[i] == scores$win_country[i]) {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, TRUE)
  } else {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, FALSE)
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Could you add a sample of your data (using `dput(head( ... ))`) so that we can reproduce your situation on our systems?

Comment: If you think an answer was the right solution for you, please think about marking it as accepted. You can do this by  pressing the tik on top left of the answer. With 15 reputation you are also able to upvote answers and questions, which will also reward useful posts. Don't feel stressed to do so though, it is totally acceptable to wait for better answers and don't press the accepted mark.

Comment: Yep I accepted the answer below. thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if your entry is `NA` use `is.na()`. Your `if` get's interrupted as soon as it calls the `NA` value from the dataframe, so it does not come to compare it `==NA`. Make sure, this one is on top, since it would interrupt your `if` again, if you don't call it first. Therefore you stop your `if` directly when you call `NA`

```
scorevector <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(scores)) {
  if (is.na(scores$win_country[i])) {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, FALSE)
  }
  else if (scores$home_country[i] == scores$win_country[i]) {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, TRUE)
  } else {
  scorevector <- c(scorevector, FALSE)
    }
  }
```

---

Since you did not provide an reproducible example, I tried it with the build in dataset `airquality`, which got `NA` values. You can copy and run this code.

```
df<-airquality

scorevector <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (is.na(df$Ozone[i]) ) {
    scorevector <- c(scorevector, TRUE)
  } else {
    scorevector <- c(scorevector, FALSE)
  }
}

scorevector
```

Comment: A much simpler version is this using `ifelse`: `scorevector2 <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  scorevector2[i] <- ifelse(is.na(df$Ozone[i]), TRUE, FALSE )
}`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann yes, that's true. I try to use the syntax of the questionare, since it is much more likely he will learn from the main problem. Also it does not provide space for the third if: `scores$home_country[i] == scores$win_country[i]`.  But thank you for your reminder, in my code it can be simplified. That's true

Comment: That did it thanks so much!!!! Just needed that is.na function and it turned out the way I wanted. Sorry for not giving more information on the dataset,  I'll do that next time if I have a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

First. It's not a great idea to loop over the rows of a dataframe. Instead you can achieve your result like so:

```r
scores <- data.frame(
  home_country = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  win_country = c("A", "E", NA, "D")
)

scores$scorevector <- FALSE
scores$scorevector[scores$home_country == scores$win_country] <- TRUE
scores
#>   home_country win_country scorevector
#> 1            A           A        TRUE
#> 2            B           E       FALSE
#> 3            C        <NA>       FALSE
#> 4            D           D        TRUE
```